# how can we write a query in sql for changing from upper to lower case for two columns at a time

Tags: sql

can we write a query for changing  for upper to lower case for two columns at a time

Comment: Perhaps you should show in your question how you would approach this for one column.  You seem to have some code in mind.

Comment: we will write it by using this query                         update table
set col1 = LOWER(col1)    can we this by including two columns.

Comment: Then extend the logic this way: set col1 = LOWER(col1), col2 = LOWER(col2), etc.

Comment: what database platform?  Show example data and expected output